# Multiple Async AJAX Calls Best Practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, asynchronous

I have a question regarding the "Best Practice" for making multiple AJAX calls on a single page.

I need to make 5 isolated calls, asynchronously. I know that $.ajax is async by nature, but I was curious if there's a "cleaner" or "better" way to do multiple AJAX calls.

An example of including multiple AJAX calls is below:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api.github.com/users/ralvarenga",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) { console.log(data); }
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://api.github.com/users/dkang",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) { console.log(data); }
  });
});
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [$.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/).

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php")).done(function (a1, a2) {
    //all AJAX requests are finished
});
```

Or:

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) )
    .then( successFunction, failureFunction );
```

Comment: So I made the when and then method work. Though it's not behaving as I imagine it would. Take a look at this fiddle and check out the responses in the console. http://jsfiddle.net/8us9t/2/ ...why is the single request just returning the data, but the multi-request returning a larger object with a ton of other stuff. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: So I ended up getting what I wanted like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8us9t/4/, but I'm just curious if there's a cleaner way then specifying that I only want the JSON response via the following "data[2].responseJSON" .

Comment: What you are proposing, runs the `done`, `then` functions when both ajax calls are successful, however I don't think this is what OP is asking. each call can fail or succeed without interfering with each other (e.g. loading news and products list at same time). This solution should only be used when success in both calls is necessary to proceed.